# Library file some ten times larger than the executable even though all functions are being used

Tags: c, visual-c++, static-libraries, static-linking

I have been working on making some libraries for a while, and I have a testing system where I'll have one solution per library, with one project building the library and another project testing and executing from it, in Visual Community 2019. The "library tester" executable tests and uses all functions from the library along with other code for its own execution, yet even in a Debug build the executable is between 5-10 times smaller than the library in physical size. As I understand it, a C library contains symbol definitions so that whenever the library tester project references a function, the linker will essentially copy out the .lib code into the .exe. If my (loose) understanding of the process is correct, how can it be that all symbols are being resolved yet the .lib dwarfs the .exe?

Exact measurements:

on Debug build, the exe is 109KB, the .lib is 527KB.

on Release build, the exe is 30KB, the .lib is 2.9MB.

Comment: It looks like a debug information stored in the object files. Do not worry.

Comment: The real test is to make a DLL. The size of a static library is less relevant as it's an intermediate build product.

Comment: I deliberately disabled debug information in the Release build - I'm not worried I'm just fascinated. I also just now started a new project with an identical set up; the .lib had empty c files, the executable project just had int main() { return 0; } and still even with an empty project we have 10KB executables and 50KB libraries - what on earth is visual linking to to bloat the size like that?

Comment: Are you using "Link-time code generation" in the release build? That would explain the large size of that config's object library.

Comment: Yes I am - could you please explain how it affects build size - there surely isn't any code to generate from a near empty project?

Comment: @IdioticShrike generate the map file - you will see what is included in your executable file and how big it is.

Comment: How many translation units (vulgo: modules) do you compile into the library? The linker takes only these units that are needed to resolve references of the executable.